# Compare cells value in gridview for greater value c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview

i want to check if obtained marks are not greater than total marks in a gridview while entering data in runtime. what is the best way to implement that?
the logic i have developed is something like this:

```
if(DG_Result .Rows .Count >0)
        {
            for(int x=0;x<DG_Result .Rows .Count ;x++)
            {
                if(DG_Result .Rows [x].Cells ["DGTotal"].Value !="" & DG_Result .Rows [x].Cells ["DGObt"].Value !="")
                {
                    if(Convert .ToInt32(DG_Result .Rows [x].Cells ["DGObt"].Value)>Convert .ToInt32(DG_Result .Rows [x].Cells ["DGTotal"].Value ))
                    {
                        DG_Result.Rows[x].Cells["DGObt"].Value = "";
                        MessageBox.Show("Obtained Marks Cannot be greater than Total Marks");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but i am not sure which event shall i use for this. i used timer but its not working. any suggestions? Cheers

Comment: Is it windows forms grid view? Doesn't it have an `EditEnded` event or something like that?

Comment: You do not show how the code is started, a button press? If you loop through the rows and check these cells, then every time the user changes one of the cells in question, then you have to run this against all cells again. As Emad suggest, it may be easier to hook up an event to check if the cells value is valid after the user types a value into a cell.

Comment: @JohnG if you look at my question i have already mentioned that i have developed the logic and i know its perfect but i dont find any event where should i call it upon or hook it up with. so that if a user when enters values in DGObt then and press tab or enter key it should prompt the user with the message.

Comment: This will depend on what control you are using. It is unclear from your question what this control is as C# and vb.net do not use a `GridView`. If you are using a `DataGridView`, then you can place your perfect code in one of the events that fires when the users enters data into one of the cells in question. If its not a `DataGridView` because you are using some other framework then I am confident there will be a similar event.

Comment: For sure it's a DataGridView as a matter of fact. All i am looking for is a suitable event. i just found "CellLeave" Event so when the user leaves that cell by pressing any key it shows the message. But there is another problem now. user needs to press key twice to get the message. :Like when first i leave the cell it does nothing but when i move one step more forward or backward it prompts. isn't there any other more efficient way?

Comment: @Emad yes its a winform application in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Attach an event handler to your datagridview. Imaging it is called `dataGridView1`:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellValidating += new
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValidating);
```

Then write the event handler where you will have your validation logic:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    string headerText = 
        dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;

    // Abort validation if cell is not in the target column.
    // The target column is the column you want to validate
    if (!headerText.Equals("TargetColumn")) return;

    // Confirm that the cell is not empty.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText =
            "Your error message goes here.";
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

You can read more about validation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc(v=vs.110).aspx).